# select nodes with matching but unknown values in child nodes

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

My XML datasource is:

```
<impact_categories>
    <impact_category>
        <name>Cat1</name>
        <impact_levels>
            <impact_level>
                <name>Insignificant</name>
            </impact_level>
        </impact_levels>
    </impact_category>
    <impact_category>
        <name>Cat2</name>
        <impact_levels>
            <impact_level>
                <name>Lowest</name>
            </impact_level>
        </impact_levels>
    </impact_category>
    <impact_category>
        <name>Cat3</name>
        <impact_levels>
            <impact_level>
                <name>Insignificant</name>
            </impact_level>
        </impact_levels>
    </impact_category>
</impact_categories>
```

I need to select all impact_category nodes that have an identical set of impact_level children. In the example, I want to select Cat1 and Cat 3 because their child values are both "Insignificant". Having done some things with those nodes I then need to select the next batch of impact_category nodes that have a different set of matching impact_level children (in this example Cat2 whose value is "Lowest"), and so on.

My problem is that I won't know what the values will be until run-time, and they could be different for different users. I'm a relative XPath novice so have no idea how to do this. I've spent hours looking online and in books but all the examples I've found assume that you are matching on known values. Apologies if this is something really simple, but I'm really stuck.

Comment: A quite "hard nut" (as we'd say in german) for a newbie. Look up [muenchian grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=muenchian+grouping)

Comment: But how do you want to select specific impact categories for further processing if you don't know the possible values of the impact levels upfront?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `deep-equal` function which allows you to compare subtrees so you can for instance select

```
let $cat := /impact_categories/impact_category
return $cat[some $cat2 in ($cat except .) satisfies deep-equal(impact_levels, $cat2/impact_levels)]
```

to return `impact_category` elements with an `impact_levels` deep-equal child to another `impact_category`s `impact_levels`.

In XSLT 2.0 you could also group `<xsl:for-each-group select="/impact_categories/impact_category" group-by="impact_levels/impact_level/name">`, if you know there is only a single such descendant you can group the elements together easily that way, if there several you might want to compute a finger print or use XSLT 3.0 and composite keys.